# Replacing a bike with different tire sizes

Tags: tire

[image]                                                 I recently bought a bike with different tire sizes (20" rear and 18" front) now I want to replace both with a 16" tire is it possible? Also, the rear suspension mechanism is totally unknown to me even to the fellow whom I bought the bike from. Is it also replaceable because i want to change it[image]
Pardon my imbecilic queries guys, this is my very first bike :)

Comment: Assuming you're asking about wheels. If the bike has rim brakes, then no, it's not possible.

Comment: Can you post a photo?  It sounds like a chopper bike, one with a smaller rim at the front than the back.

Comment: Look closely at the sides of the tires.  You should see something like "20-2.1" and "53-406".  The former is the "traditional" inch measurement while the latter is "ISO".  All sorts of games are played with "traditional" numbers, so you must match the 3-digit portion of the ISO (the rim diameter) if you wish to use the same rim.  (The 2-digit piece of the ISO is the width and need not match real closely.)

Comment: That rear suspension looks like an elastomer-based soft tail. It's something that comes around occasionally. In fact some new road bikes are getting that treatment to take the harshness out of some rougher roads.

Comment: Is it good because honestly I don't have any idea about those the only ones i saw were the coiled ones

Comment: @user29991 It's essentially a block of rubber that acts as a spring.

Comment: As I have read all you good peoples comments I have somehow one way or another learned a thing or two on how it goes with the possibilities of tinkering with a bike. I am grateful too that you guys took the time to explain things to me rest assured I took them to mind. especially to Mr. David Richerby, to you sir I wish to read more from you in this wonderful site for bikers. Stay safe always and have fun biking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bike modification/alteration](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/43369/bike-modification-alteration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be a little confused?

The tire of a bike is the rubber bit which sits around the rim - on that rim only one size of tire will fit comfortably. If you wanted to change both to 16" you would also have to replace the rim and the rear cassette. Do you mean can you buy two new 16" wheels so the entire setup?

Comment: Yes exactly I want to buy a new pair of tires size 16" ( rubber and rim) both as replacement to the original tires of the bike when I bought but I don't know and sure if it will fit in to the frame

Comment: Thanks a lot user37883391 for pointing out and answering my query

Comment: Your welcome - hope you enjoy your bike!

Answer (score 2):

Changing the rim sizes on both wheels is likely to be expensive even if it's possible. If you *really* want both wheels the same size, you should probably keep the 18" and change the 20" to 18". If you really want 16" wheels (it might be a good idea to tell us *why* as there may be an alternative) it could be cheaper to replace the bike given the difficulties around brakes. This is especially true as there's suspension you don't want.

Comment: I think I'll go with your changing the 20" with an 18" instead. I like 16" because I think I "feel" theres  an added fun in the 16" :)

Comment: It still won't be easy or cheap - make sure tou've got the whole job planned out before spedning any money.  It could easily cost more than the bike is worth.  Now I can see the pictures clearly on a big screen the V-brakes at the back are going to be a problem.