# Bike modification/alteration

Tags: tire, brakes, suspension

[image]

[image]

Base on the photos as shown, is it possible to apply the following modification/s and/or alteration/s:

a. replacement of wheels from 20" rear-18" front to 16" both rear and front.

b. installation of disc brake since the bike frame and fork is designed for rim brakes.

c. replacement of the "uncommon" rear suspension to a more common suspension easily found in shops.

The bike is an aluminum alloy.

Comment: Dude, please don't post the same question twice. Thanks for wasting my time.

Comment: My apologies it's just that this is my very first bike and I can't help myself but tinker with it. I know it sounds stupid and irritable for the most of you guys who have been biking all your life and have in-depth knowledge about the whole biking thing. I agree, posting the same stupid query is twice the idiocy.

Comment: I suspect you're having problems finding 18" tyres and tubes?   20" and 16" would be normal sizes, but eighteen's a bit weird.  Or is there some other motivation for the rim changes?

Comment: Also, a folder's party trick is folding.  Everything else takes secondary importance to folding.  So, if you don't need a bike that folds, get a bike that doesn't fold and suddenly all this tweaking becomes a lot more possible.  Or own two bikes, that works as well.

Comment: No I didn't knew 18" tyres are hard to find it's really just my fancy to have16" tyres on it, thinking it would be more fun to run on smaller wheels, but also having 16" tyres would probably lower the frame thus increasing the risk of the pedals striking the ground. I guess for now I'll just have to enjoy the bike as it is.

Comment: As I have read all you good peoples comments I have somehow one way or another learned a thing or two on how it goes with the possibilities of tinkering with a bike. I am grateful too that you guys took the time to explain things to me rest assured I took them to mind. especially to Mr. David Richerby, to you sir I wish to read more from you in this wonderful site for bikers. Stay safe always and have fun biking

Comment: If you want a bike to upgrade and tinker with and learn the in's and out's, this is not the bike to do so on. Save some money and get a commuter, MTB, or road bike and tinker with that. Or get a frame and build it slowly until you have a complete bike, by which time you will have it exactly how you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a. replacement of wheels from 20" rear-18" front to 16" both rear and front.

In principle. However, as pointed out in a [comment](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/43348/replacing-a-bike-with-different-tire-sizes#comment90402_43348) to the other version of this question, you'll have problems with your brakes because both they and the axles are in fixed positions and the brakes need to be agains the wheel rims. Also, changing the wheel size as you suggest that would lower the back of the bike by 2" and the front by 1", and I'd be worried about the increased risk of the pedals striking the ground while cornering. Why would you want to do this, anyway?

> b. installation of disc brake since the bike frame and fork is designed for rim brakes.

If you have to ask, the answer is almost certainly "no". Fitting disc brakes would require attaching the mounts to the forks and rear frame and, if that's even possible, it needs to be done very well, since disc brakes generate huge forces. Indeed, the forks and frame themselves might not even be strong enough to cope with those forces.

> c. replacement of the "uncommon" rear suspension to a more common suspension easily found in shops.

I don't even understand why you'd want to do that. Rear suspension is an integral part of any bike design; "replacing" it would involve completely re-engineering the frame.

If you want to tinker with a bike, it's best to get one with a standard diamond frame. Folding bikes are unique designs and every aspect of them is designed around the need to fold. That means they tend to use weird geometries and heavily custom components that are unique to that particular design.

Comment: I am enlightened by your explanations and I totally agree with all of it, Perhaps as someone who has got his very first bike I guess I'd just have to suppress my urges to tinker with the goddamn thing. Everyone I knew told me to buy a bike that suits me, I bought this one and thought it would suit me best if I tinker with it, alter it to suit what i thought is fun. I guess I should leave it as is and have fun biking.

Comment: As I have read all you good peoples comments I have somehow one way or another learned a thing or two on how it goes with the possibilities of tinkering with a bike. I am grateful too that you guys took the time to explain things to me rest assured I took them to mind. especially to Mr. David Richerby, to you sir I wish to read more from you in this wonderful site for bikers. Stay safe always and have fun biking

Answer (score 1):

The suspension fitted looks like a block of elastomer.  Its not so much suspension as an absorber for road buzz.

This is a flat road bike, so forget doing anything worse than a gravel/shingle path.

If you really want to undo it, find a round block of steel or aluminium the same size, drill a hole down the middle, and swap the squishy bit out.

Avoid cutting or damaging the elastomer, otherwise you won't have the option of refitting it.

Comment: That said - I personally took a 20" folder up and down a local shingle climb with 318m elevation over 4 km, so 8% on average.  It was achievable, but a lot of work for a slow trip, despite gearing of 46/32.

Answer (score 0):

Given the angle and thickness of that rear swing-arm I'm not sure you'd be able to mount a calliper there. It just seems like it's too far away for a standard 160mm disc. Maybe you could but you'd need a bracket to angle the calliper right.